# Passing props to a react component wrapped in withRouter() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using React-Router v4 to navigate in my React app. The following is a component wrapped in the `withRouter()` function to make it able to change route on click:

```
const LogoName = withRouter(({history, props}) => (
  <h1
    {...props}
    onClick={() => {history.push('/')}}>
    BandMate
  </h1>
));
```

As you can see I pass the `props` to the component, which I need in order to change the class of the component. The problem here is that `props` is `undefined` in the `<LogoName>` component. I need to be able to change the class of this component when I click on another component, like this:

```
<LogoName className={this.state.searchOpen ? "hidden" : ""} />
<div id="search-container">
  <SearchIcon
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    className={this.state.searchOpen ? "active" : ""} />
  <SearchBar className={this.state.searchOpen ? "active" : ""}/>
</div>
```

Here is how I handle the click. Basically just setting the state.

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    searchOpen: false
  }
}

handleClick = () => {
  this.setState( {searchOpen: !this.state.searchOpen} );
}
```

Is there a way for me to pass `props` to a component that is wrapped inside the `withRouter()` function or is there a similar way to create a component which has the ability to navigate with React-Router and still receive props?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that while destructuring, you want to `destructure props` but you are not passing any prop named `props` to `LogoName` component

You can change your argument to

```
const LogoName = withRouter((props) => (
  <h1
    {...props}
    onClick={() => {props.history.push('/')}}>
    BandMate
  </h1>
));
```

However you can still destructure the props like @Danny also suggested by using the spread operator syntax like

```
const LogoName = withRouter(({history, ...props}) => (
  <h1
    {...props}
    onClick={() => {history.push('/')}}>
    BandMate
  </h1>
));
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. The navigation is going to be much simpler now when I know this.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help :)

Comment: @KyleRichardson, I think you misunderstood my explanation, what I meant was that the way OP has written it, it meant that he is trying to destruture props from props which doesn't exist. I am aware of the other method that DannyDelott has provided

Comment: @KyleRichardson You could edit my answer if the wording is confusing

Answer (score 6):

You're close, just spread the props in your function signature as well:

```
const LogoName = withRouter(({ history, ...props }) => (
  <h1
    {...props}
    onClick={() => {history.push('/')}}>
    BandMate
  </h1>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import  {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
class Login extends React.Component
{
   handleClick=()=>{
      this.props.history.push('/page');
   }
   render()
  {
     return(
          <div>
          .......
            <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Redirect</button>
          </div>);
  }
}

export default withRouter(({history})=>{
  const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Login  history={history} classes={classes} />
    )
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/27114335)