# Unit testing React stateless component wrapped with withRouter() in Enzyme, how to pass match parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to test a React functional component that I've wrapped in withRouter from react-router-dom. The component structure is as below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';


export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
    closeModalLinkPath: string;
    closeModalFunction: any;
}

const RouterWrappedComponent= withRouter(({ match, history, closeModalLinkPath, closeModalFunction }: Props) => {

return (<div></div)
    }
});

export default RouterWrappedComponent;
```

This structure works perfectly in the browser, however I am having difficulty writing unit tests. Due to the nature of the component I need an accurate match object but I can't find any way of passing this through on generation.

```
var routerWrappedComponent= Enzyme.mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={[`/studio/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/manage`]}>
    <RouterWrappedComponent closeModalFunction={() => { }} closeModalLinkPath={`/studio/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`} />
</MemoryRouter>);
```

Despite the component's props inheriting from `RouteComponentProps` I can't add this to the components props and I can't find any variation of `MemoryRouter` that will let me pass match in through props, can anyone help?

EDIT: The withRouter wrapping came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244413/passing-props-to-a-react-component-wrapped-in-withrouter-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so there doesn't seem to be any way to pass match as a parameter but I've found a pretty elegant solution. The reason match is empty on the component is because it's being directly rendered, it hasn't matched with anything. I've wrapped the component in a route that matches the `initialEntries` prop on `MemoryRouter` as below.

```
var routerWrappedComponent= Enzyme.mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={[`/studio/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/manage/11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`]}>
       <Route path={`/studio/:customerId/:page/:serviceId`} component={() =>  
    <RouterWrappedComponent closeModalFunction={() => { }} closeModalLinkPath={""} />
</MemoryRouter>);
```

and presto, match is filled

```
match: { path: '/studio/:customerId/:page/:serviceId',
    url: '/studio/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/manage/11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    isExact: true,
    params:
     { customerId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
       page: 'manage',
       serviceId: '11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' } }
```